# How do I include the contents of a contenteditable element in a HTMX request?

Tags: htmx

I'd like to post the contents of a contenteditable field/div whenever it changes. `hx-trigger="change"` didn't trigger, but using `hx-trigger="blur"` is okay. How do I submit the value of the contenteditable div in the request?

```
  <div id='parent-div'>
      <div contenteditable='true'
           hx-post="/update_db"
           hx-trigger="blur"
           hx-target="#parent-div"
           hx-swap="outerHTML">
               Hello, I am a content editable field
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe htmx supports submitting contenteditable values out of the box. You'd probably need to mirror the content text within contenteditable to a a hidden input and move the `hx` attributes to the parent div.

You could use something like https://alpinejs.dev/ or htmx's companion https://hyperscript.org/

With hyperscript you could do it with something like this:

```
<div id='parent-div' 
    hx-post="/update_db"
    hx-trigger="blur"
    hx-target="#parent-div"
    hx-swap="outerHTML">

    <div id="editordiv" contenteditable='true'>
    Hello, I am a content editable field
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="editor" _="on keyup from #editordiv put its innerHTML into me" />
</div>
```

I found an old reference from the htmx Discord that offers another way of doing this:

```
<form hx-post="/whatever" 
        hx-vals="javascript: editable:htmx.find('#myEditable').innerHTML"> ...
```